# Writing time difference to file

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a log file that logs time differences between executions of a loop. I am very new to Python and it seems I can't quite make it work.

This is the loop:

```
def writeData(self):
    f = open('logfile','w')
    timeInMs = 0
    while True:
        lastTimeInMs = timeInMs
        timeInMs = long(round(time.time() * 1000))
        timeDifference = timeInMs - lastTimeInMs
        print(timeDifference) #write to console
        f.write(str(timeDifference) + "\n") #write to logfile
        doc = {'foo': 'bar'}
        self.db.save(doc)
```

It prints the `timeDifference` just fine to the console, but the `logfile` remains empty. However, writing to the `logfile` works just fine if I use absolute times!

```
f.write(str(timeInMs) + "\n")
```

Can somebody please tell me why that is and how I can fix this problem? I would have expected `print` and `write` to behave the same way. Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling `f.close()` at some point?

Comment: `long(round(time.time() * 1000))` Why is it necessary for you to round time before calculating time difference. Why don't you want: `t1 = time.time()` and `tdiff = time.time() - t1` ?

Comment: I just copied this line from somewhere else when I googled for how to log time in ms with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect the output to appear in the file directly after the `f.write()` call, you have to call `f.flush()` after the call to `f.write()`.

Although `f.close()` was suggested, it is not the solution to the problem. `f.close()` effectively calls `f.flush()` before closing the file; however, that would be too late, so to get the written data to appear in the file without closing it use `f.flush()`.

Comment: That did it for me, thanks! Any ideas why I need to flush for `timeDifference` but not for `timeInMs`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the writ functions deals with these expression: `f.write(str(timeDifference) + "\n")` 
Why don't you change to

```
timeDifference = str(timeDifference)+"\n"
f.write(timeDifference)
```

As Khelwood pointed in comments don't forget to close the open file with a `f.close()` at the end of the function outside the while-loop

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is the same as before. It works with `timeInMs`, but not with `timeDifference`. I have yet to close the file, but since it works perfectly with `timeInMs` I figured it would not be necessary for now.

Comment: You could also consider using the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.info) for those tasks.